# UITextView add Constraints navigation push Vc not smooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

Why is UITextView add Constraints navigation push Vc not smooth?

Rhis is my interface:

[image]

And this is the textView Constraints:

[image]

If I add this Constraints, RootVc push to this Vc, it is not smooth.  If I remove the textView Constraints, every thing is ok?

Why?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I looked at the images you posted, and it seems they're in Chinese. StackOverflow is an English-language site (and [there is a Spanish version which is currently in beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish)), but unfortunately there isn't a Chinese version of StackOverflow at this time...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have added your images inline and improved your English